# Appending to an existing text file

Tags: vb.net

Using VS2013 with VB.NET and trying to accomplish the following...

I have an input file (inputfile.txt) that is a delimited file (could be any delimiter) and looking to read the entire file and append a value to the end of each line.  The output needs to be directed to a new file.

Any thoughts or direction on accomplishing this?

```
Dim line As String 
Dim r As New IO.StreamReader("c:\bcc\test1.txt") 
Dim o As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\bcc\test2.txt", True)
line = r.ReadToEnd
While Not (line Is Nothing)
   o.WriteLine(line & ";test") 
   o.Flush() 
End While
r.Close() 
o.Close()
```

The problem appears to be my while loop; it enters the loop but never comes out. My input file has one line but it never stops. Thoughts?

Comment: This MSDN article might help: [How to: Open and Append to a Log File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `ReadLine`->modify->`WriteLine` to new file? I would do it like that.

Comment: I understand the ReadLine -> modify -> WriteLine approach but am struggling with syntax.  Any sample code you can share?

Comment: Sorry, can't get formatting to work..

Comment: @GeorgeVaisey Code formatting only works in the question body, not in comments. Please post your code inline, and indent it by four spaces in order to have it show up as code.

Comment: @GeorgeVaisey To create inline code spans, used `backticks`, not 'single quotes'. However, your code should be in the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This could help. "Appending text to a file in VB.Net". http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets8p5.html